# Join a string from name/value data in a different order in JSON

Tags: json, string, python-2.7

Here are two examples of the format of JSON data I am loading:

```
"address": {
    "locality": "London",
    "postal_code": "L1 1RE",
    "region": "London",
    "address_line_1": "1 Tower Road"
  },
  "date_of_creation": "2013-01-02",
   ....

"address": {
    "postal_code": "KY7 6SD",
    "address_line_2": "A Business Park",
    "address_line_1": "Headquarters",
    "locality": "Fife",
    "region": "Glenrothes"
  },
  "date_of_creation": "2010-02-01",
```

I would like to return a string that joins the address object in a specific order which is out of sequence of the JSON data. i.e

```
str = address['address_line_1'] + ',' + address['address_line_2'] + ',' 
+ address['locality'] + ',' + address['region'] + ',' + 
address['postal_code']
```

However not every address object contains all they keys, the order isn't always the same and in the first example, I don't want to join the values if they are the same (locality and region).

What is the best way to create this string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the problem step by step.

Problem 1: Not all address have all keys.

Solution: Create a function to return the value if key exists otherwise empty string

```
def get_value(key, json_obj):
    if key in json_obj.keys(): # Check if key exists
        return json_obj[key] # if yes will return value
    return "" # Otherwise empty str
```

Problem 2: You dont want to get same values to be counted twice:
Solution.

```
list_of_attributes_to_find = ['address_line_1', 'address_line_2', 'locality', 'region','postal_code' ]  # All the values which you want to exclude

def Create_str(address): 
    list_of_values = [] #For each address

    for key in list_of_attributes_to_find: # for each key
        if get_value(key, address) and get_value(key, address) not in list_of_values:
            list_of_values.append(get_value(key, address))  # Check if the value is not empty and value is not already in the output list_of_values
    return ",".join(list_of_values) # Return the output with formatted output

address = {
    "postal_code": "KY7 6SD",
    "address_line_2": "A Business Park",
    "address_line_1": "Headquarters",
    "locality": "Fife",
    "region": "Glenrothes"
  }
```

Output:

```
Headquarters,A Business Park,Fife,Glenrothes,KY7 6SD
```

Comment: That is incredible! Thank you

Comment: My pleasure ..:)